Showing that $R \in \text{CAlg}(\text{Sp})$ is the unit in $\text{Mod}_R(\text{Sp})$
Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\Mod}{Mod} \DeclareMathOperator{\CAlg}{CAlg} \DeclareMathOperator{\Sp}{Sp} R \in \CAlg(\Sp)$, where $\Sp^{\otimes}$ is the symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category of spectra, and $M, N \in \Mod_R(\Sp)$ a module over $R$.
In HA, Thm. 4.5.2.1, Lurie shows that the category $\Mod_R(\Sp)$ can be equipped with a symmetric monoidal structure and by HA, Thm. 4.4.2.8, the underlying spectrum of the ("relative") tensor product $- \otimes_R -$ can be computed by the geometric realization of a bar construction (HA, Con. 4.4.2.7, which is somewhat complicated).
In particular, if one unravels HA, Con. 4.4.2.7, one should get the following simplicial spectrum:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\op}{op} \DeclareMathOperator{\BBar}{Bar}
\BBar(M,R,N): N(\Delta^{\op}) \to \Sp, \qquad [n] \mapsto M \otimes R^{\otimes n} \otimes N,
$$
with degeneracy and face maps given by tensoring with $R$ and multiplying on the left or on the right in the correct positions; of course, the simplicial identities are to be considered up to homotopy, and these higher coherences are additional structure, given by the construction itself.
Moreover, in HA, Thm. 4.4.3.16, Lurie shows that $-\otimes_R -$ is unital, with unit $R$ seen as a module over itself; the proof is somehow complicated and referential.
Question. Can we use the bar construction to get unitality? This is what is done here, Sec. II.62b, but I don't quite get the formalities.
More specifically: if we consider $\BBar(R,R,M)$, we morally have an extra degeneracy map given by just tensoring on the left
$$\newcommand{\SSS}{\mathbb{S}}s_{-1}:= (u: \SSS \to R) \otimes -: R \otimes R^{\otimes n} \otimes M \to R \otimes R^{\otimes n+1} \otimes M.$$
In classical simplicial homotopy theory, if we are in such a situation with a simplicial set $\DeclareMathOperator{\Set}{Set} X: N(\Delta^{\op}) \to \Set$, we can define a simplex $Y: N(\Delta^{\op}) \to \Set$ such that $X$ is the décalage of $Y$ , and then one has that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\dec}{dec} |\dec(Y)| \simeq Y_0 \qquad (\star)
$$
This really uses (I believe) point-set constructions and the extra degeneracy; all the homotopies here are strict identities so it's easier to deal with higher coherences.
How can I do the same, i.e. formally define $Y: N(\Delta^{\op}) \to \Sp$ such that $\BBar(A,A,M) = \dec(Y)$, in this higher setting? Maybe using the $s_{-1}$ defined above. Then the rest should follow formally as shown in the notes I've linked.

First let us introduce some notation and fix some conventions. We will solve the problem in an arbitrary symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$, with a given commutative algebra $R$ and a given left $R$-module $M$.
We will not distinguish in notation between a $1$-category and its nerve. We will write $\mathbb{F}_*$ for the category of pointed finite sets. Given a natural number $n$, we write $\langle n\rangle=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, with $0$ being the base point.
We let $\sigma\colon\Delta\to\Delta$ be the functor sending $[n]$ to $[n+1]$ and $\alpha\colon [n]\to[m]$ to $\sigma(\alpha)\colon [n+1]\to[m+1]$ defined by $\sigma(\alpha)(n+1)=m+1$ and $\sigma(\alpha)(i)=\alpha(i)$ for other $i$. We let $\tau\colon\Delta\to\Delta$ be the functor sending $[n]$ to $[n+1]$ and $\alpha\colon [n]\to[m]$ to $\tau(\alpha)\colon [n+1]\to[m+1]$ defined by $\tau(\alpha)(0)=0$ and $\tau(\alpha)(i)=\alpha(i)+1$ for other $i$. We will generally consider $\sigma$ and $\tau$ as functors $\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\Delta^\mathrm{op}$. We also define $\mathrm{Cut}^\mathrm{cycl}\colon\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbb{F}_*$ (which is not a functor!) to be an assignment sending an object $[n]$ to $\langle n\rangle$ and a morphism corresponding to $\alpha\colon[n]\to[m]$ in $\Delta$ towards the morphism $\alpha^*\colon\langle m\rangle\to\langle n\rangle$ given by
$$
\alpha^*(i)=\begin{cases}
    0&\text{if $i=0$,}\\
    j&\text{if $j\neq 0$ and $\alpha(j-1)<i\leq\alpha(j)$,}\\
    n&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
It holds that the composite assignment $\mathrm{Cut}^\mathrm{cycl}\circ\sigma\colon\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbb{F}_*$ is a functor. (It helps to draw out what it does in simple cases.) Note that $\mathrm{Cut}^\mathrm{cycl}\circ\sigma$ maps every morphism $[m]\to[n]$ in $\Delta^\mathrm{op}$ to an active morphism $\langle m+1\rangle\to\langle n+1\rangle$ in $\mathbb{F}_*$ that sends $m+1$ to $n+1$. Write $\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}^\mathrm{tv}$ for the wide subcategory of $\mathbb{F}_*$ on those morphisms, so that we have a functor $\mathrm{Cut}^\mathrm{cycl}\circ\sigma\colon\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}^\mathrm{tv}$.
We will construct a simplicial diagram $Y\colon\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{C}$ such that $Y\circ\tau\colon\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Bar}(R,R,M)$. This will establish the latter as a kind of décalage of $Y$, and we will make sure that $Y_0\simeq M$. We build $Y$ in two steps: by straightening-unstraightening, there is a tensoring functor
$$
\mathcal{C}^\otimes_\mathrm{act}:=\mathcal{C}^\otimes\times_{\mathbb{F}_*}\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}\to\mathcal{C}, (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto x_1\otimes\ldots\otimes x_n
$$
(that does not extend to a functor with all of $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ as domain). We will hence construct a functor $\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes_\mathrm{act}$.
It is HA, Prop. 4.5.1.4 that $\mathrm{LMod}_R(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)\simeq\mathrm{Mod}^{\mathbb{F}_*}_R(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)$, the fiber over $R$ of the $\infty$-category of $\mathbb{F}_*$-modules introduced in HA, Def. 3.3.3.8. When doing the constructions of Lurie inside the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories, instead of the $1$-category of simplicial sets, we can instead work with the fiber over $\langle1\rangle$ of the $\infty$-operad $\overline{\mathrm{Mod}}^{\mathbb{F}_*}(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)^\otimes\to\mathbb{F}_*$ defined similarly to HA, Def. 3.3.3.1 (but as said, for us the constructions are performed in suitable $\infty$-categories, not in simplicial sets). Explicitly, this means that $\mathrm{Mod}^{\mathbb{F}_*}(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)$ is a full subcategory of
$$
\mathrm{Fun}_{\mathrm{Fun}(\{1\},\mathbb{F}_*)}(\{\langle 1\rangle\}\times_{\mathrm{Fun}(\{0\},\mathbb{F}_*)}\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*},\mathcal{C}^\otimes)
$$
(where $\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}$ is the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Fun}([1],\mathbb{F}_*)$ on the semi-inert morphisms), namely the full subcategory on functors $\{\langle 1\rangle\}\times_{\mathrm{Fun}(\{0\},\mathbb{F}_*)}\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ sending morphisms in the domain corresponding to inerts in $\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}$ towards inerts in $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$. Here, a morphism in $\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}$ is inert if the source and target functors $\mathrm{Fun}([1],\mathbb{F}_*)\to\mathbb{F}_*$ both map it towards inert morphisms in $\mathbb{F}_*$.
Such a functor $\{\langle 1\rangle\}\times_{\mathrm{Fun}(\{0\},\mathbb{F}_*)}\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ corresponds to a pair $(A,N)$ of a commutative algebra $A$ and an $(A,A)$-module $N$, in the following way: those semi-inerts $\langle 1\rangle\to\langle n\rangle$ sending $1$ to the basepoint are sent to $(A,\ldots,A)$, and those semi-inerts $\langle 1\rangle \to\langle n\rangle$ sending $1$ to $1\leq j\leq n$ towards $(A,\ldots,A,N,A,\ldots,A)$, with the object $N$ in place $j$.
We can recognize $\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}^\mathrm{tv}$ as a subcategeory of $\{\langle 1\rangle\}\times_{\mathrm{Fun}(\{0\},\mathbb{F}_*)}\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}$, namely the one whose obects are the semi-inert maps $\langle 1\rangle\to\langle n+1\rangle$ sending $1$ to $n+1$, and whose morphisms are commutative squares
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\langle 1\rangle @>{\mathrm{id}}>>\langle 1\rangle\\
@V{m+1}VV @VV{n+1}V\\
\langle m+1\rangle @>>{f}> \langle n+1\rangle
\end{CD}
$$
where $f$ is an active map. The restriction of $\{\langle 1\rangle\}\times_{\mathrm{Fun}(\{0\},\mathbb{F}_*)}\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ to this subcategory lands in $\mathcal{C}^\otimes_\mathrm{act}$ by definition, as the functor has to live over $\mathrm{Fun}(\{1\},\mathbb{F}_*)$. We can hence use the equivalence $\mathrm{LMod}_R(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)\simeq\mathrm{Mod}^{\mathbb{F}_*}_R(\mathcal{C}^\otimes)$ to consider the pair $(R,M)$ as a functor $\{\langle 1\rangle\}\times_{\mathrm{Fun}(\{0\},\mathbb{F}_*)}\mathcal{K}_{\mathbb{F}_*}\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ living over $\mathrm{Fun}(\{1\},\mathbb{F}_*)$, and then consider its restriction to  $\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}^\mathrm{tv}$ to get a functor
$$
\widetilde{M}\colon\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}^\mathrm{tv}\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes_\mathrm{act}
$$
living over $\mathbb{F}_*$. The composite
$$
\Delta^\mathrm{op}\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Cut}^\mathrm{cycl}\circ\sigma}\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}^\mathrm{tv}\xrightarrow{\widetilde{M}}\mathcal{C}^\otimes_\mathrm{act}\xrightarrow{\otimes}\mathcal{C}
$$
is the functor $Y$ we are after.
We can see that $(\mathrm{Cut}^\mathrm{cycl}\circ\sigma)\circ\tau\colon\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathbb{F}_{*,\mathrm{act}}^\mathrm{tv}$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Cut}\circ\sigma\circ\tau\cong\mathrm{Cut}\circ\tau\circ\sigma$. The object $R_R$, which is $R$ considered as a right $R^\mathrm{op}$-module, can be given as the composite
$$
\Delta^\mathrm{op}\xrightarrow{\tau}\Delta^\mathrm{op}\xrightarrow{R}\mathcal{C}^\otimes,
$$
as follows from the definition of the object $M_A$ in II.62a. in the lecture notes by Hebestreit/Wagner that you linked. Using this, one can verify that the forgetful maps $Y\circ\tau\to M$ and $Y\circ\tau\to R$ make
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} 
Y\circ\tau @>>> M\\
@VVV @VVV\\
{R_R} @>>> R
\end{CD}
$$
a pullback diagram of functors $\Delta^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ (where $M$ is considered as such a functor in the same way it is in the definition of $\mathrm{Bar}(R,R,M)$ in II.62a. of the aforementioned notes). This establishes that $Y\circ\tau\simeq\mathrm{Bar}(R,R,M)$, with which we are done.
